# VBA programming, Sorting Algorithm with Filters/Advanced Filters

Tags: vba, excel

I would to optimize asset allocation of a portfolio. I a database and would like to find the best asset doing multiple fitlers until we find the right one. I would like to do this for several maturity so I wanted to know if it is possible to use Advanced Filters completely in VBA, instead of working with an Excel table I wanted to do all the sorting process and just print the name of the selected asset a the end of the process.

Comment: This does not ask a specific question. Please show the work that you have done so far and where you are getting stuck. Only then will the programmers on this site be able to assist you.

Answer (score 0):

A disconnected recordset has some filtering. This shows how to sort with one.

```
Set Inp = WScript.Stdin
Set Outp = Wscript.Stdout
Sub Randomise
    Randomize 
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    With rs
        .Fields.Append "RandomNumber", 4 

        .Fields.Append "Txt", 201, 5000 
        .Open
        Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
            .AddNew
            .Fields("RandomNumber").value = Rnd() * 10000
            .Fields("Txt").value = Inp.readline
            .UpDate
        Loop
        .Sort = "RandomNumber"
        Do While not .EOF
            Outp.writeline .Fields("Txt").Value

            .MoveNext
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```